# Criteria for density of subgroup of diffeomorphism group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, topological-groups

Let $C^{\infty,\star}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote the non-commutative topological group of smooth diffeomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to itself with $\circ$ as multiplication and let $\emptyset\subset X\subseteq C^{\infty,\star}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.  Are there (non-trivial) conditions one can use to verify if the closure of the group generated by $X$, $\overline{\langle X\rangle}$, equals to all of $C^{\infty,\star}(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

I'm thinking of some type of a group-theoretic version of the Weierstrass's result (since obviously these objects need not be algebras).

Comment: The fine topology?

Comment: Yes exactly.  But if no reasonable cirteria are availalbe in that setting, I'd settle with soemtihng weaker (though prefarably not).

Comment: The question is fuzzy; consider the case $d=1$. Do you mean uniform convergence of functions and all their derivates on compact subsets? In that case, the real-analytic diffeomorphisms are dense by Weierstrass.

Comment: There is this result: STONE-WEIERSTRASS THEOREMS FOR GROUP-VALUED FUNCTIONS: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02772227.pdf